# How can I find a series of bytes in a file and replace them with another buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Basically I'm reading a file in NodeJS using `fs.readFile`, and this returns a buffer of the file.

I then want to find a certain pattern of bytes inside this buffer, and replace them with a new buffer of the same size (or pad the rest to 00 if it's smaller.)

I tried setting the buffers to strings and using `.replace`, but that causes the filesize to double, not to mention it just wasn't really practical.

```
let data = await readFile('mytest.exe');

var pattern = new Buffer.from([
  0x90, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90
])
```

Cross reference pattern with the file bytes and find it, Convert a string that is 32 bytes to buffer, and override the buffer with the 32 bytes of the string and then save it in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Buffer.indexOf](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_indexof_value_byteoffset_encoding) is all you need to find the position, then use [Buffer.copy](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_copy_target_targetstart_sourcestart_sourceend) to override it.

```
/* Replaces all occurences of "pattern" in the "data" with "replace",
   if "replace" is shorter than "pattern" the rest will be filled with 0s, a longer "replace" will get trimmed of */
function replace(/*Buffer*/ data, /*Buffer*/ pattern, /*Buffer*/ replace) {
 let position = data.indexOf(pattern);

 while (position !== -1) {
   data.fill(0, /*from*/ position, /*to*/ position + pattern.length);

   replace.copy(
     /*to*/ data,
     /*at*/ position, 
     /*from*/ 0, 
     /*to*/ pattern.length
   );      
   // continue search:
   position = data.indexOf(pattern, /*starting at*/ position + pattern.length + 1);
 }
}
```